# Log4jNestedDiagnosticContextFilter for Log4j 2

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

As of Spring 4.2.1 the `Log4jNestedDiagnosticContextFilter` is deprecated following Apache's EOL declaration for log4j 1.x as seen below.

[image]

I have found the corresponding JIRA Ticket ([SPR-13400](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13400)) but how can I bring Log4j 2 into the Spring environment to do the same as the `Log4jNestedDiagnosticContextFilter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented it myself by copying the `Log4jNestedDiagnosticContextFilter` and adapt the logger to Log4j 2 and change `NDC` to `ThreadContext`.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class CustomRequestLoggingFilter extends AbstractRequestLoggingFilter {

  protected final Logger log4jLogger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());

  @Override
  protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
    if (log4jLogger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log4jLogger.debug(message);
    }
    ThreadContext.push(getNestedDiagnosticContextMessage(request));
  }

  @Override
  protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
    ThreadContext.pop();
    if (ThreadContext.getDepth() == 0) {
      ThreadContext.removeStack();
    }
    if (log4jLogger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log4jLogger.debug(message);
    }
  }

  protected String getNestedDiagnosticContextMessage(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return createMessage(request, "", "");
  }
}
```